# Why isn't Bruce Willis's character in the Sixth Sense self-aware?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-sixth-sense

Why doesn't Bruce Willis's character realize he is dead?

If I remember correctly, the plot takes place several months after he is killed. Shouldn't there have been some clues during that time? They do imply that he thinks his wife isn't speaking to him because she's angry, but is it really possible that she was the only person he expected to interact with?

Additionally, it seems that all the other ghosts in the movie know they're dead. So perhaps another question would be do all ghosts in The Sixth Sense go through a "transition period" where they don't realize they're dead? At what point to they become aware of it?

Comment: I don't think Mr Shyamalan put that much thought into this. He probably rather wanted a stunning twist at the end. Interresting question, though.

Comment: Loved ones and work/vocation pretty much sum up life. What else is there? Sure there's other stuff too, but those two are at the center. Right? It'll be a while until looking elsewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cyclist has no idea he's dead

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This line from [Cole](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167404/quotes) I think summed it up best, "They don't see each other. They only see what they want to see. They don't know they're dead."

And, except for the girl trying to save her sister, I don't know if you could definitively say any of the other ghosts knew they were ghosts. I think the "They only see what they want to see" bit is the key here. In a way the ghosts are making their own reality.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't remember that last sentence in Cole's quote there. I guess I was only thinking of the little girl when I said "the rest of them seem to realize..."

Comment: When I read this question I was like `Damn that ruined the movie for me too` and when I read your answer I was like `Nope wait still one of the greatest suspense/horror/ghost movies ever.`

Comment: I think this point was also supposed to be hinted at living human beings who just as well tend to only see what they choose to see - while this is not necessarily a totally concious decision.

Comment: But at least the ghosts think, and therefore they exist, at least in Descartes's universe

Comment: Good answer - except when you consider the day or three after Bruce Willis' character dies ...wouldn't there be flowers, memorials, etc. around his home? Wouldn't he see his wife being depressed for a while?  Wouldn't he find that odd?  Unless the "they only see what they want" denial can go *that far*.  This answer does work, but for me there's still a rather large plot-hole there.

Comment: @BruceWayne Only if we assume being a ghost is just like being alive, including continuity of time. It makes more sense if you imagine it more like being in a dream, where there are gaps, jumps and shifts between times and locations, but it doesn't feel like it. The ghosts only see what they want to see, and *we* only see what they see: when we see a cut to a scene and assume there was some skipped filler where Bruce's character walks some streets, goes to the toilet, buys and drinks a bottle of water, says hi to the shopkeeper, etc etc, actually there was *nothing* before.

Comment: Still something is odd here. Malcolm Crowe didn't use the toilet for months. He didn't go to a store to buy a thing to eat. How can someone see he never eats and urinates, but he doesn't realize something is odd with him?

Comment: @EtackSxchange “They only see what they want to see”. Even for the living, denial and delusion are very powerful and are mental blocks that pretty much everyone experiences in their lives. As others have suggested, if you’ve ever not known you were dreaming until you woke up, this could be like that. A dream-like existence with a powerful delusion of live and rationalization. I mean who really catalogs how much they go to the bathroom? I myself have forgotten to use the restroom while hyperfocused and much later realized how badly I need to when the task is done.

Answer (score 22):

I am from Sri Lanka, and the idea that ghosts are unaware of the fact that they are dead is not totally alien here. I'm pretty sure Shyamalan was aware of these types of myths.

Answer (score 11):

From what I remember from the movie (and other similar movies), it is often stressed that the ghosts the child sees are the soul/spirits of people who have not accepted their death yet, or who still have something to accomplish in this world.

- The girl needed to show her father that her (step?) mother was poisoning her.
- Cole's grandmother wanted to tell Cole's mom something important (that would drastically alter Cole's mom's feelings towards her own mother).
- The cyclist was presumably killed on impact (given the head wound) and therefore never realized she died. She seemed puzzled by people not looking at her, so she was probably on her way to realizing she died.

And for Bruce Willis' character, he needed to both accept and understand his death. He could not accept the reality of his death and therefore held on.

Being a ghost in the real world is similar to being in purgatory. You're there until you finish what needs to be finished. Although for ghosts in the real world, it's often more voluntary (spirit chooses to not move on), rather than forced.

Answer (score -2):

I would also add to the answer @Evan give that the basic idea of the ghosts still being around other people (hence "ghost" status/name), is that they are people that did not realized they are dead, and still behave as they normally would.

Another GREAT movie with such example is Passengers (2008) with Anne Hathaway https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449487 which I suggest everyone to watch; for me was a revelation, and for sure was with much more "soul", "emotions" and "relations" in it than Sixth Sense.